# What Does Input Arguments is _

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, startup, argv, argc

I wanna know  why is result 1 for no arguments.

```
int main(int argcount, char *arglist[]) {
    int i;
    printf("Number of arguments %d\n",argcount);
    printf("Arguments list:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<argcount;i++)
        printf("%s\n",arglist[i]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: because `argv[0]` is always set the the program name.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `argc` and `argv`. Even though the names can be whatever, it will be much more clear to others if you use the defacto standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard (C11), noting especially the bold bit:

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>     `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>     implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>     intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>     from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>     supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>     shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> - ***If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>     represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>     program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>     greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>     represent the program parameters.***
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>     be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>     startup and program termination.

In other words, `argc` includes the argument representing the program name - the actual parameters to the program start at `argv[1]`. That becomes evident from the program output as per the following transcript, where the first argument is the program name:

```
pax> cat testprog.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Argument count: %d\n", argc);
    printf("Arguments:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("   %s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

pax> gcc --std=c11 -o testprog testprog.c && ./testprog 1 2 3
Argument count: 4
Arguments:
   ./testprog
   1
   2
   3

pax> ./testprog
Argument count: 1
Arguments:
   ./testprog
```

Answer (score 0):

./a.out is the first argument so that's why argcount equals to 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup. p.#2)

> — If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by
>   argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null
>   character if the program name is not available from the host
>   environment.

So the used by you environment supplies the program name in the first argument.